# Getting error while throwing a list of errors?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my project I was throwing a list of error messages

like this

```
 List<string> errorMessageList = errors[0].Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();

 throw new WorkflowException(errorMessageList);
```

and my WorkflowException class looks like this

```
/// <summary>
/// WorkFlowException class
/// </summary>
public class WorkFlowException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the WorkFlowException class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">Error Message</param>
    public WorkFlowException(List<string> message)
    {
        base.Message = message;
    }
}
```

but getting errors while assigning this list of messages to base.Message
can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exception.Message` is a `string`, not a `List<string>`, and it's read-only, so you have to pass a `string` to the base class via constructor chaining:

```
public class WorkFlowException : Exception
{
    public WorkFlowException(List<string> messages)
    : base(messages != null && messages.Count > 0 ? messages[0] : "")
    { 
      //...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can override the `Message` property:

```
public class WorkFlowException : Exception
{
    List<string> messages;

    public WorkFlowException(List<string> messages)
    { 
      this.messages = messages
    }

    public override string Message
    {
      get { return messages != null && messages.Count > 0 ? messages[0] : "" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than just showing the first message in the list, I would concat each element into a single string so that you don't lose any of the messages when throwing the exception.

Comment: The OP originally had all errors in a comma-delimited string. You can also have a `Messages` property.

Answer (score 1):

Exception.Message is a string. You're trying to assign a `List<string>` to a `string` property. **Type mismatch..** Try and format your list of strings into a single string before assigning.

Updated (Thanks Mark)
`public WorkflowException(List<string> listOfMessages) : base(String.Join(",", listOfMessages.ToArray());`

Answer (score 0):

[Exception.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx) is string. not `List<string>`

Comment: @Mark Cidade: Thanks :) I forgot that :)